# Removing the underline from an Html.ActionLink

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an Html.ActionLink on my page and I am using the following CSS on it to give it an image and try and remove the underlining.....

```
a.searchButton
{
    background-image: url(/content/images/DropAcross.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    clear:none;
}
```

Can anyone see a problem with this?  All the CSS properties seem to work apart from the text-decoration: none, which seems to leave the underline in place.

Comment: Can we see how you are creating the link?

Comment: Don't see anything obvious. Can you post the HTML as well? ("View Source" rather than the .ascx)

Comment: Do you have access to Firebug? That will tell you the answer instantly.

Comment: Is it possible another CSS rule is adding an underline via `border-bottom`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to look at the rendered html.  In Firefox or Google Chrome, right click and choose Inspect Element.

You might find something silly like the searchButton class is being applied to a span that wraps the a tag, in which case, you would get everything working except the link specific rule:

```
text-decoration:none;
```

Comment: Inspect Element in Chrome led me to the answer. There was another style that was adding a border-bottom. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I know that it is old topic, but maybe somebody will considere it helpful -
"text-decoration" attribute, mentioned above, can be passed to ActionLink by construction like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display_Name","Action_Name",null,new {style="text-decoration:none;"})
```

Comment: yes its right. we need to give "null" there, then only the style will work fine..

Answer (score 3):

Setting `text-decoration:none;` ought to work.

Is it possible that there are some other styles overriding it? Have you looked in Firebug (or similar tools) to see what styles are being applied?

One possible answer may be the `:hover`, `:visited` and `:active` pseudo classes. If they are set to have an underline, then they will override the default style for the element.